# rocket propulsion elements

Tags: propulsion, rocket-equation, education

i tried to solve the following problem

this rocket engine area is cut off at 50%   of the exit area, calculate the new Mach value.
data old engine:
P1=2068Mpa , chamber temp 2222k , flow mass 1kg/sec , k=1,3, r=345 J/kgK, At=28,7cm2, A2/At (old) = 3.3

i used this formula

[image]

ie new mach value : (0,5A2/At)^1/3,83 where 3,83=(K+1/K-1)0,5...gives 0,83 so new mach value is 0,83x2,6=2,15
is this the right aproach?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As stated now, this question is unanswerable by anyone with out that particular book. More detail will need to be added to the question.

Comment: At least give the edition, if you are referring to Sutton.

Comment: yes it is Sutton , 9th edition

Comment: Please edit the question, show your work, and give the exact numbers you calculated. If you want help with a problem give us something to figure out where you went wrong. Don't just ask us to work the problem for you.

Comment: @marble i do not ask for the calculation ie 'you to work the problem for me' , just want to know the flow charge to this problem

Comment: give the exact numbers you calculated. Show your work!

Comment: i have just edited the question with the used formulas

Comment: What value did you get for the exhaust velocity?

Comment: @ o marble..if is use formula 3-16 ( see above ):1833m/s...where P2=P3...so this gives Mach: v2/(kRT)^0.5=1.83

Comment: i recon this is not the right answer since i used T1=2222k..anyone?

Comment: You're over thinking this.  There is so much information.  You are directly given the throat area and expansion ratio.  With these two it is possible to calculate the new expansion ratio.  Exit Mach is purely a function of gamma and expansion ratio.

Comment: yes , but i need the new mach value